# Error running pod install: `UMFileSystemInterface` depended upon by `EXAV`

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-unimodules

I am developing mobile app for Android and ios using React Native. I developed app on Windows machine and run it successfully. I have a lot of modules and everything works well on Android.

Now, I am trying to install all modules on macOS. I run `npm install` and then tried to run `npx pod-install` but got this error:
`[!] Unable to find a specification for UMFileSystemInterface depended upon by EXAV`.

I thought that this problem might be because of `react-native-unimodules` and I followed documentation on how to install this module on ios, but that didn't help. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Here is my Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`, "../scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`, "../native_modules")
require File.join(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native-unimodules/package.json')"`, "../cocoapods")

platform :ios, '13.6'

target 'Capitalba' do
    
    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'    

    pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
    
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

    use_unimodules! 
    config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1')
  #   post_install do |installer|
  #     flipper_post_install(installer)
  #   end
  # end
end
```

Comment: I've run into this issue as well while upgrading my version of unimodules. What does your Podfile look like?

Comment: I ended up reverting to an older version of unimodules and my old integration

Comment: @pixelknitter I edited my post with Podfile. Platform was ios 11.0 but it didn't work. I changed it to 13.6 but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, I uninstalled the package `expo-av`:

`yarn remove expo-av` - this refreshed the lockfile

then re-installed the package:

`yarn add expo-av`

and ran the `cd ios/ && rm -rf Pods &&  pod install --repo-update` to ensure we get the freshest version.

I did the same for the package `react-native-unimodules` before this, but don't believe it was related.